# Deploying Rails 5 to a Linux server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, server

I have a computer that I would like to set up as a Linux production server for a Rails 5 application, but I don't know where to start. Does anyone know of any articles/guides that could help me? I tried searching but I didn't find anything that outlines the entire process.

Comment: I have successfully deployed a Rails 5 app following the tutorial provided by the good guys at DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

Answer (score 0):

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

The only thing that would be different for rails 5 is the rails gem version number